# How do I create enhanced sub-lists from existing lists and another variable with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I needed to take a simple list, take the first N elements from it where N comes from user input, and make a new list of dictionaries where each item contains an additional value stored in another variable. This took me way too long to figure out, so I am leaving this here in case it helps someone else save time.

The biggest challenge was discovering the new way to use [with_sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence) loops which boils down to

```
loop: "{{ range(start, end, stride) | list }}".
```

I had something like this.

```
- hosts: blah
  vars:
    user_input: N
    extra_value: 100
    simple_list:
      - item1
      - item2
      .
      .
      .
      - itemN
  tasks:
  .
  .
  .
```

I wanted to create an enhanced sub-list `{{ final_list}}` of dictionaries containing N items from `{{ simple_list }}` based on the value stored in `{{ user_input }}` which is provided by the user at run-time. I also wanted to add `value: {{ extra_value }}` to each list item in the new list.

The new list should end up looking like this:

```
final_list:
  - item: item1
    value: 100
  - item: item2
    value: 100
  .
  .
  .
  - item: itemN
    value: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The final solution looks like this:

```
- name: Create final list based on simple_list, user_input, and extra value
  set_fact:
    final_list: "{{
      final_list | default ([]) +
        [
          {
            'item': simple_list[item],
            'value': extra_value
          }
        ]
    }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1, user_input + 1, 1) | list }}"

- name: Do things with final_list
  .
  .
  .
  loop: "{{ final_list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't too picky about the output you could probably simplfy this a bit.  This will give you a list of lists.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    user_input: 4
    extra_value: 100
    simple_list:
      - item1
      - item2
      - item3
      - item4
      - item5
      - item6
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: |
        {{ simple_list[0:user_input] |
           zip_longest([],fillvalue=extra_value) |
           list }}

# TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "msg": [
#         [
#             "item1",
#             100
#         ],
#         [
#             "item2",
#             100
#         ],
#         [
#             "item3",
#             100
#         ],
#         [
#             "item4",
#             100
#         ]
#     ]
# }
```